# Set variables in the Gitlab CI/CD programmatically

Tags: python, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I would like to set up 2 variables in the Gitlab CI/CD from a Python script. The variables provided below,

```
General pipelines: 

    Custom CI config path -> `build/ci/.gitlab-ci.yml`

Environment variables: 

    WE_PROJECT_ID -> p007-999
```

How do I achieve that? I will be also interesting (and helpful) to know if I can interact with the `.gitlab-ci.yml` from a shell script or Python code.

PS: 
I am able to set the environmental variables for the local machine using the Python, I need to somehow upload (if this is correct wording) them to the Gitlab

Comment: There is a dependency called `python-gitlab` I am looking atm can solve the issue.